# How to save text after deleting lines to a new file in Vim?

Tags: command-line

I am very new to Vim and this problem has stumped me.

I am using vim to delete all lines containing a certain word. I have tried saving the edited text with to a new file but it always contains the exact same lines as the original file. What command do I use to save my edited text to a new file and keep the original file? Bear in mind, my file is very large and will take a long time to move to the bottom.

Comment: I have used  :w then typed a new filename, but that file is exactly the same as the original, it isn't saving the changes I've made

Comment: @Emma try: `vim +g/word/d +'w bar' +q! foo`, where `foo` is the original file and `bar` is the target file, and `word` is the filtering word. What happens?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand your need.

If you only want to save lines filtered into a new file, you can play with

```
" equivalent to "grep the_word > the-filename"
:let @a =''
:v/the_word/y A
:call writefile(@a, 'the-filename')
```

However a more likely scenario is: if you do multiple edits, `:saveas` will permit to save the current buffer under in another file. But the current filename won't be changed. If you do some more edits, and hit `:save`/`:update`, the old file will get overwritten. You need to call `:file` in order to change the filename of the current buffer. After that, all following saves will be done to the new file, leaving the old one unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but let's say you've opened a file called foo, and after editing it you want to save the result to a new file called bar. To do this you can type `:saveas bar`.

If a file called bar already exists, you will have to tell vim to overwrite it by adding an exclamation mark `:saveas! bar`.

To navigate between the two files foo and bar, you can type `:b#` or`<C-^>` (the Control modifier key and the `^` key pressed at the same time).